# List directly installed packages only

Tags: chocolatey

With

```
choco list --local-only
```

I get a list of all installed packages. Is there a way to filter this list to exclude packages that were automatically installed to fulfill some other package dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no mechanism within Chocolatey to provide that information.